# pyaudio installation failure in colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I installed speech recognition, later I installed pipwin to download pyaudio indirectly because it doesn't support newer python version. But the installation method is not working properly

```
pip install speechrecognition
pip install pipwin
pipwin install pyaudio
```

it shows me this error

```
File "<ipython-input-10-b8d7c797a59c>", line 1
    pipwin install pyaudio
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what wrong I am doing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

Get your pyAudio file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio). Then open the command line and redirect to the directory that your pyaudio file contains. Then type `pip install 'filename'`
replace the filename with downloaded pyaduio file name